# How do I synchronize threads similar to a barrier, but with the caveat of the amount of threads being dynamic?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have tried to create a function that works similar to a barrier function, except it can handle the active amount of threads changing. (I can't seem to get it to work either by destroying and reinitializing the barrier whenever a thread exits the function loop).

My issue is that I can't get my replacement function to run properly, i.e. the program softlocks for some reason.
So far nothing I've tried has worked to ensure that the threads are synchronized and the program doesn't softlock.
I've tried using barriers, I've tried making the exiting threads enter barrier wait as well, to help with the barriers (but I couldn't figure out how to not softlock with the exiting threads, as I always ended up with some thread(s) invariably being left inside the barrier_wait function).

This is my replacement function for the pthread_barrier_wait function:

```
void SynchThreads()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if (threadsGoingToWait < maxActiveThreads)
    {
        threadsGoingToWait++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condVar2);
        pthread_cond_wait(&condVar1, &lock);
    } else
    {
        threadsGoingToWait=1;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&condVar1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

To change the value of maxActiveThreads, I have the threads do the following before they exit the function loop:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&tlock);
    maxActiveThreads--;
    if (maxActiveThreads>0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&condVar2, &tlock);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&condVar1);
    }
    else pthread_cond_broadcast(&condVar2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&tlock);
```

I have the pthread variables initialized before the thread creation as this:

```
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, maxActiveThreads);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&tlock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condVar1, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condVar2, NULL);
```

I have no clue why the program is softlocking right now, since as far as I know, so long as there's at least 1 thread either remaining or in the waiting fireld, it should release the other threads from the cond_wait they're in.

Edit:
If I remove the condVar2 from being used, and instead end the function loop with a barrier_wait, the program no longer softlocks, however it still doesn't function as if it's being synchronized properly.
To give some more detail as to what I'm working on: I'm trying to make a sequential Gaussian elimination function parallel. So the issues I've had so far is that either the matrix has the wrong values, or the vectors have the wrong values, or they all have the wrong values. I was hoping by having synchronization points distributed as following would fix the issue of synchronization errors:

```
static void* gauss_par(void* params)
{
/*getting the threads and the related data*/
    for (int k = startRow; k < N; k+=threadCount) /* Outer loop */
    {
        SynchThreads();
        /* Division step */
        SynchThreads();
        /* Vector y and matrix diagonal */
        SynchThreads();
        for (int i = k+1; i < N; i++)
        {
            /* Elimination step */
            SynchThreads();
            /* Vector b and matrix zeroing */
            SynchThreads();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Ada language uses protected objects as shared resources for concurrent programs. The protected object is protected against inappropriate concurrent access, thus the barriers and locking are controlled by the protected object and not by the tasks calling the object. This approach eliminates the problem of changing numbers of tasks (threads) calling the protected object. See https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/tasking.html#

Comment: You are perhaps missing a notion of a "generation." When a thread "arrives" or "waits," it notes the current generation at the time of its arrival, and it waits on a condition variable until that generation changes.  (The generation is incremented when the waiting threads are released.)  Perl's [Thread::Barrier](https://metacpan.org/release/MROGASKI/Thread-Barrier-0.300/source/Barrier.pm#L92) is a readable implementation of this.  Java's [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) is an easy-to-misuse generalization of all this.

Comment: (Also, `pthread_cond_wait` ought to be _called in a loop_ until its associated predicate changes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a preliminary, I see `&lock` in your `SyncThreads()` and `&tlock` in your other code snippet.  These almost certainly do not go with each other, because proper protection via a mutex relies on all threads involved using *the same* mutex to guard access to the data in question.  I'm having trouble coming up with a way, in C, that the expressions `&lock` and `&tlock` could evaluate to pointers of type `pthread_mutex_t *`, pointing to the same object.  Unless maybe one of `lock` and `tlock` were a macro expanding to the other, which would be nasty.

With that said,

> I have tried to create a function that works similar to a barrier function, except it can handle the active amount of threads changing. (I can't seem to get it to work either by destroying and reinitializing the barrier whenever a thread exits the function loop).

Destroying and reinitializing the (same) barrier object should work if you can ensure that no thread is ever waiting at the barrier when you do so or arrives while you are doing so.  But in practice, that's often a difficult condition to ensure.

Barriers are a somewhat specialized synchronization tool, whereas the Swiss army knife of thread synchronization is the condition variable.  This appears to be the direction you've taken, and it's probably a good one. However, I suspect you're looking at CVs from a functional perspective rather than a semantic one.  This leads to all sorts of issues.

The functional view is along these lines: *a condition variable allows threads to block until another thread signals them*.

The semantic view is this: *a condition variable allows threads to block until some testable *condition* is satisfied*.  Generally, that condition is a function of one or more shared variables, and access to those is protected by the same mutex as is used with the CV.  The same CV can be used by different threads at the same time to wait for different conditions, and that can make sense when the various conditions are all related to the same data.

The semantic view guides you better toward appropriate usage idioms, and it helps you come to the right answers on questions about who should signal or broadcast to the CV, under what conditions, and even whether to use a CV at all.

Diagrammatically, the basic usage pattern for a CV wait is this:

```
                 |
+++++++++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                V               CRITICAL REGION +
+           +- - - - - +                         +
+           : optional :                         +
+           + - - - - -+                         +
+                |                               +
+                V                               +
+ +-----------------------------+                +
+ | Is the condition satisfied? | <-+            +
+ +-----------------------------+   |            +
+      |                   |        |            +
+      | Yes               | No     | on waking  +
+      V                   V        |            +
+ +- - - - - +        +---------+   |            +
+ : optional :        | CV wait |---+            +
+ + - - - - -+        +---------+                +
+      |                                         +
+++++++|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
       V
```

In particular, since the whole point is that threads don't proceed past the wait unless the condition is satisfied, it is essential that they check after waking whether they should, in fact, proceed.  This protects against three things:

1. the thread was awakened via a signal / broadcast even though the condition it is waiting for was not satisfied;
2. the thread was awakened via a signal / broadcast but by the time it gets a chance to run, the condition it was waiting for is no longer satisfied; and
3. the thread woke despite the CV *not* having been signaled / broadcasted to (so there's no reason to expect the condition to be satisified, though it's ok to continue if it happens to be satisfied anyway).

With that in mind, **let's consider your pseudo-barrier function.**  In English, the condition for a thread passing through would be something like "all currently active threads have (re-)reached the barrier since the last time it released."  I take `maxActiveThreads` to be the number of currently active threads (and thus, slightly misnamed). There are some simple but wrong ways to implement that condition, most of them falling over in the event that a thread passes through the barrier and then returns to it before some of the other threads have passed through.  A simple counter of waiting threads is not enough, given threads' need to check the condition before proceeding.

One thing you can do is switch which variable you use for a waiter count between different passages through the barrier.  That might look something like this:

```
int wait_count[2];
int wait_counter_index;

void cycleBarrier() {
    // this function is to be called only while holding the mutex locked
    wait_counter_index = !wait_counter_index;  // flip between 0 and 1
    wait_count[wait_counter_index] = 0;
}

void SynchThreads() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // A thread-specific copy of the wait counter number upon arriving
    // at the barrier
    const int my_wait_index = wait_counter_index;

    if (++wait_count[my_wait_index] < maxActiveThreads) {
        do {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condVar1, &lock);
        } while (wait_count[my_wait_index] < maxActiveThreads);
    } else {
        // This is the thread that crested the barrier, and the first one
        // through it; prepare for the next barrier passage
        assert(wait_counter_index == my_wait_index);
        cycleBarrier();
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

That flip-flops between two waiter counts, so that each thread can check whether the count for the barrier passage it is trying to make has been reached, while also providing for threads arriving at the *next* barrier passage.

Do note also that although this can accommodate the number of threads decreasing, it needs more work if you need to accommodate the number of threads *increasing*.  If the thread count is increased at a point where some threads have passed the barrier but others are still waiting to do so then the ones still waiting will erroneously think that their target thread count has not yet been reached.

**Now let's consider your strategy when modifying `maxActiveThreads`.**  You've put a wait on `condVar2` in there, so what condition does a thread require to be satisfied in order to proceed past that wait?  The `if` condition guarding it suggests `maxActiveThreads <= 0` would be the condition, but surely that's not correct.  In fact, I don't think you need a CV wait here at all.  Acquiring the mutex in the first place is all a thread ought to need to do to be able to reduce `maxActiveThreads`.

However, having modified `maxActiveThreads` does mean that other threads waiting for a condition based on that variable might be able to proceed, so broadcasting to `condVar1` is the right thing to do.  On the other hand, there's no particular need to signal / broadcast to a CV while holding its associated mutex locked, and it can be more efficient to avoid doing so.  Also, it's cheap and safe to signal / broadcast to a CV that has no waiters, and that can allow some code simplification.

Lastly, what happens if all the other threads have already arrived at the barrier?  In the above code, it is the one to crest the barrier that sets up for the next barrier passage, and if all the other threads have reached the barrier already, then that would be *this* thread.  That's why I introduced the `cycleBarrier()` function -- the code that reduces `maxActiveThreads` might need to cycle the barrier, too.

That leaves us with this:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    maxActiveThreads--;
    if (wait_count[wait_counter_index] >= maxActiveThreads) {
        cycleBarrier();
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condVar1);
```

Finally, **be well aware that all these mutex and cv functions can fail**. For robustness, a program must check their return values and take appropriate action in the event of failure.  I've omitted all that for clarity and simplicity, but I am rigorous about error checking in real code, and I advise you to be, too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with this! Although I was well past my brain being mush from having sat for about 9 hours with the issue before I posted my ask. Therefore, the issues I was having were mostly due to my own incapability to think. Though in addition to that, my hardware was unknowingly also insufficient for running 16 threads, hence I was on like iteration 3 of trying to get a speed-up over sequential before I had to post an ask since nothing seemed to work. The answer you have given will be of great use for situations where the track I was heading in is the only solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

An Ada language solution to this problem is shown below. This example implements a producer-consumer pattern supporting N producers and M consumers. The test of the solution implements one producer and 5 consumers, but the solution is the same for any positive number of producers and consumers, up to the limits of your hardware.

This example is implemented in three files. The first file is the package specification, which defines the interface to the producer and consumer task types. The second file is the package body which contains the implementation of the task types and their shared buffer. The shared buffer is implemented as an Ada protected object. Ada protected objects are passive elements of concurrency which implicitly control their own locking and unlocking based on the kind of methods implemented.
This example uses only protected entries which acquire an exclusive read-write lock on the object only when their guard condition evaluates to true. The guard conditions are implicitly evaluated at the end of each entry. Tasks suspended because the guard condition on an entry evaluates to FALSE are placed in an entry queue with FIFO ordering by default.

*package specification:*

```ada
package multiple_consumers is
   task type producer is
      entry Set_Id(Id : Positive);
      entry stop;
   end producer;

   task type consumer is
      entry Set_Id(Id : Positive);
      entry stop;
   end consumer;

end multiple_consumers;
```

*package body:*

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body multiple_consumers is

   type Index_Type is mod 10;

   type Buffer_Type is array (Index_Type) of Integer;

   ------------
   -- Buffer --
   ------------

   protected Buffer is
      entry Enqueue (Item : in Integer);
      entry Dequeue (Item : out Integer);
   private
      Buff        : Buffer_Type;
      Write_Index : Index_Type := 0;
      Read_Index  : Index_Type := 0;
      Count       : Natural    := 0;
   end Buffer;

   protected body Buffer is
      entry Enqueue (Item : in Integer) when Count < Buff'Length is
      begin
         Buff (Write_Index) := Item;
         Write_Index        := Write_Index + 1;
         Count              := Count + 1;
      end Enqueue;

      entry Dequeue (Item : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Item       := Buff (Read_Index);
         Read_Index := Read_Index + 1;
         Count      := Count - 1;
      end Dequeue;
   end Buffer;

   --------------
   -- producer --
   --------------

   task body producer is
      Value : Integer := 1;
      Me    : Positive;
   begin
      accept Set_Id (Id : in Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end Set_Id;

      loop
         select
            accept stop;
            exit; -- Exit loop
         else
            select
               Buffer.Enqueue (Value);
               Put_Line
                 ("     Producer" & Me'Image & " produced " & Value'Image);
               Value := Value + 1;
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("Producer" & Me'Image & " stopped.");
   end producer;

   --------------
   -- consumer --
   --------------

   task body consumer is
      My_Value : Integer;
      Me       : Positive;
   begin
      accept Set_Id (Id : Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end Set_Id;

      loop
         select
            accept stop;
            exit; -- exit loop
         else
            select
               Buffer.Dequeue (My_Value);
               Put_Line
                 ("Consumer" & Me'Image & " consumed " & My_Value'Image);
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("Consumer" & Me'Image & " stopped.");
   end consumer;

end multiple_consumers;
```

*main procedure:*

```ada
with multiple_consumers; use multiple_consumers;

procedure Main is
   subtype Consumer_Idx is Positive range 1 .. 5;
   Consumer_list : array (Consumer_Idx) of consumer;
   P             : producer;

begin
   for I in Consumer_list'Range loop
      Consumer_list (I).Set_Id (I);
   end loop;
   P.Set_Id (1);
   delay 0.01; -- wait 0.01 seconds
   P.stop;
   for I in Consumer_list'Range loop
      Consumer_list (I).stop;
   end loop;

end Main;
```

*Output:*

```
     Producer 1 produced  1
Consumer 1 consumed  1
     Producer 1 produced  2
Consumer 2 consumed  2
Consumer 3 consumed  3
     Producer 1 produced  3
     Producer 1 produced  4
     Producer 1 produced  5
Consumer 4 consumed  4
Consumer 5 consumed  5
     Producer 1 produced  6
     Producer 1 produced  7
Consumer 1 consumed  6
Consumer 2 consumed  7
Consumer 3 consumed  8
     Producer 1 produced  8
     Producer 1 produced  9
     Producer 1 produced  10
Consumer 4 consumed  9
Consumer 5 consumed  10
Consumer 1 consumed  11
     Producer 1 produced  11
     Producer 1 produced  12
Consumer 2 consumed  12
     Producer 1 produced  13
Consumer 3 consumed  13
     Producer 1 produced  14
Consumer 4 consumed  14
     Producer 1 produced  15
Consumer 5 consumed  15
     Producer 1 produced  16
Consumer 1 consumed  16
     Producer 1 produced  17
Consumer 2 consumed  17
Consumer 3 consumed  18
     Producer 1 produced  18
     Producer 1 produced  19
Consumer 4 consumed  19
     Producer 1 produced  20
Consumer 5 consumed  20
     Producer 1 produced  21
Consumer 1 consumed  21
     Producer 1 produced  22
Consumer 2 consumed  22
     Producer 1 produced  23
Consumer 3 consumed  23
     Producer 1 produced  24
Consumer 4 consumed  24
     Producer 1 produced  25
Consumer 5 consumed  25
     Producer 1 produced  26
Consumer 1 consumed  26
     Producer 1 produced  27
Consumer 2 consumed  27
Consumer 3 consumed  28
     Producer 1 produced  28
     Producer 1 produced  29
Consumer 4 consumed  29
     Producer 1 produced  30
Consumer 5 consumed  30
     Producer 1 produced  31
Consumer 1 consumed  31
     Producer 1 produced  32
Consumer 2 consumed  32
Consumer 3 consumed  33
     Producer 1 produced  33
     Producer 1 produced  34
Consumer 4 consumed  34
     Producer 1 produced  35
Consumer 5 consumed  35
     Producer 1 produced  36
Consumer 1 consumed  36
     Producer 1 produced  37
Consumer 2 consumed  37
     Producer 1 produced  38
Consumer 3 consumed  38
     Producer 1 produced  39
Consumer 4 consumed  39
     Producer 1 produced  40
Consumer 5 consumed  40
     Producer 1 produced  41
Consumer 1 consumed  41
     Producer 1 produced  42
Consumer 2 consumed  42
Consumer 3 consumed  43
     Producer 1 produced  43
     Producer 1 produced  44
Consumer 4 consumed  44
     Producer 1 produced  45
Consumer 5 consumed  45
     Producer 1 produced  46
Consumer 1 consumed  46
     Producer 1 produced  47
Consumer 2 consumed  47
Consumer 3 consumed  48
     Producer 1 produced  48
     Producer 1 produced  49
Consumer 4 consumed  49
     Producer 1 produced  50
Consumer 5 consumed  50
     Producer 1 produced  51
Consumer 1 consumed  51
     Producer 1 produced  52
Consumer 2 consumed  52
     Producer 1 produced  53
Consumer 3 consumed  53
     Producer 1 produced  54
Consumer 4 consumed  54
     Producer 1 produced  55
Consumer 5 consumed  55
     Producer 1 produced  56
Consumer 1 consumed  56
     Producer 1 produced  57
Consumer 2 consumed  57
Consumer 3 consumed  58
     Producer 1 produced  58
     Producer 1 produced  59
Consumer 4 consumed  59
     Producer 1 produced  60
Consumer 5 consumed  60
     Producer 1 produced  61
Consumer 1 consumed  61
     Producer 1 produced  62
Consumer 2 consumed  62
Consumer 3 consumed  63
     Producer 1 produced  63
     Producer 1 produced  64
Consumer 4 consumed  64
Consumer 5 consumed  65
     Producer 1 produced  65
     Producer 1 produced  66
Consumer 1 consumed  66
Consumer 2 consumed  67
     Producer 1 produced  67
     Producer 1 produced  68
Consumer 3 consumed  68
     Producer 1 produced  69
Consumer 4 consumed  69
     Producer 1 produced  70
Consumer 5 consumed  70
     Producer 1 produced  71
Consumer 1 consumed  71
     Producer 1 produced  72
Consumer 2 consumed  72
     Producer 1 produced  73
Consumer 3 consumed  73
     Producer 1 produced  74
Consumer 4 consumed  74
     Producer 1 produced  75
Consumer 5 consumed  75
     Producer 1 produced  76
Consumer 1 consumed  76
Producer 1 stopped.
Consumer 1 stopped.
Consumer 2 stopped.
Consumer 3 stopped.
Consumer 4 stopped.
Consumer 5 stopped.
```